# Url having # at end

Tags: bug

Sir , I have a e-commerce website on wordpress. After everything done from my backend I started testing website on mobile devices but sir my website pages urls are not refreshing properly. One incident is, when I clicked my account option of woocomerce then it redirected me to my account section but after that no link worked , I was confused , later on I checked url of that page then I found that there was a  # after slash like  example.com/my-ac/# . And when I manually removed it and refresh the page everything worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your permalink. Goto WP dashboard Settings → Permalink.